# Logstash alternative to receive messages from AWS SQS and batch store in AWS S3

Tags: logstash, amazon-sqs, audit-logging, audit-trail

I need the ability to store logs as batches in AWS S3 as text files formatted appropriately for JSON-SerDe.

Example of how one of the batched log files would look on S3, quite important that the datetime format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

```
{"message":"Message number 1","datetime":"2020-12-01 14:37:00"}
{"message":"Message number 2","datetime":"2020-12-01 14:38:00"}
{"message":"Message number 3","datetime":"2020-12-01 14:39:00"}
```

Ideally these would be stored on S3 every 5 seconds or when queued messages hit 50 but also be configurable.

---

I've almost managed to get this working with Logstash using the [sqs input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-sqs.html) and the [s3 output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html) using the below config

```
input {
  sqs {
    endpoint => "AWS_SQS_ENDPOINT"
    queue => "logs"
  }
}

output {
   s3 {
     access_key_id => "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
     secret_access_key => "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
     region => "AWS_REGION"
     bucket => "AWS_BUCKET"
     prefix => "audit/year=%{+YYYY}/month=%{+MM}/day=%{+dd}/"
     size_file => 128
     time_file => 5
     codec => "json_lines"
     encoding => "gzip"
     canned_acl => "private"
   }
}
```

The problem is the S3 output plugin requires the `@timestamp` field which isn't compatible with our query tool. If you use the mutate filter to remove @timestamp or change to datetime then it will not process the logs. We can't store the datetime field and @timestamp for every record as that drastically increases the amount of data we need to store (millions of logs).

Are there any other software alternatives for achieving this result?

---

Updated config which is working with Logstash thanks to [Badger][https://stackoverflow.com/users/11792977/badger]

```
input {
  sqs {
    endpoint => "http://AWS_SQS_ENDPOINT"
    queue => "logs"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "[@metadata][year]" => "%{+YYYY}"
      "[@metadata][month]" => "%{+MM}"
      "[@metadata][day]" => "%{+dd}"
    }
    remove_field => [ "@timestamp" ]
  }
}

output {
   s3 {
     access_key_id => "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
     secret_access_key => "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
     region => "AWS_REGION"
     bucket => "AWS_BUCKET"
     prefix => "audit/year=%{[@metadata][year]}/month=%{[@metadata][month]}/day=%{[@metadata][day]}"
     # 1 MB
     size_file => 1024
     # 1 Minute
     time_file => 1
     codec => "json_lines"
     encoding => "gzip"
     canned_acl => "private"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any dependency on @timestamp in the s3 output code. You have created one by using a sprintf reference to it in `prefix => "audit/year=%{+YYYY}/month=%{+MM}/day=%{+dd}/"`. You can move those sprintf references to a mutate+add_field filter which adds fields to [@metadata], then remove @timestamp, then reference the [@metadata] fields in the prefix option.

Comment: Amazing, wasn't aware of the @metadata which looks to work perfectly! Thanks! I'll add updated config above for anyone else who comes across this.

Comment: Did you end up using this @Nick? Does it seem to be reliable?

Comment: It's not in production yet but seems to be working perfectly.